# Unable to generate HTML to Excel data using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am trying to download the excel file which has all the contents showing on HTML page (including formatting mainly wrapping the text in particular column width).

As of now I have achieved success in:
Downloading excel file from HTML page.
Getting the same formatting as HTML page.

Not achieved success in:
Wrapping in the text for particular column.
And above code states var j and k are not declared.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
<script>
    var jgtable = "<table id=\"testTable\" summary=\"ChangeLog\" cellpadding = 10 cellspacing = 0 border=1><caption>Change Log</caption><tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>Date</th><th>Change/Correction/Clarification</th><th>Type</th><th>QID</th><th>Action/Clarification required</th><th>Done/Tested</th><th>SP ID</th><th>SP Comments</th><th>Done/Tested</th><th>PM ID</th><th>PM Comments</th><th>Set of Changes</th><th>Time Spent<br>on Client<br>Changes</th><th>Time<br>Spent on<br>PM Changes</th>";
    var z = ^f('Q1').size();^
    for(var j=1,j<=z;j++) //total number of rows entered out of 250; it may be only 85 so final output will have 85 rows of data
    {
        jgtable = jgtable + "</tr><tr>";
        for(var k=1;k<16;k++) //Total hard core 15 columns
        {
            if(j==1 || j== 13 || j==14 || j==15){ jgtable = jgtable + "<td>^f('Q'+k)[j].toNumber()^</td>"; } //numeric
            if(j==2 || j== 5 || j==6 || j==8 || j==9 || j==11 || j==12){ jgtable = jgtable + "<td>^f('Q'+k)[j].get()^</td>"; } //open
            if(j==3 || j== 4 || j==7 || j==10){ jgtable = jgtable + "<td>^f('Q'+k)[j].valueLabel()^</td>"; } //open
        }
    }
    jgtable = jgtable + "</tr></table>"
    document.write(jgtable);
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I guess with ur assistance, I have managed to place the code in better conditional formatting..

Comment: What are the carets for in the "var z" line?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles :: Actually I am programming all this on online tool named as "ConfirmIT" [ front end ASP.net and Back end as SQL ]. So in order to refer a question's size, I have used carets sign which is fine.

Comment: Can anyone please help me for the above mentioned code???